# is it possible to migrate SQL Server database instance to a previous verison?

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012-express

my sharepoint database (SQL Server 2012 Evaluation) is running out of space (10GB), I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 license I would like to use.

- Is it possible to migrate my SQL Server 2012 db instance to version
- SQL Server 2008 R2? Will the new db be compatible with my sharepoint?
- Is there any documentaion to do this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to cleanly downgrade versions due to compatibility and feature differences.
The best you can do if you want to go from a newer version to an older version is generate create scripts, ensure they do not utilize unsupported features and/or use SSIS to transfer data from one instance to another.